# Servlet filter for caching

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm creating a servlet filter for caching. The idea is to cache the response body to memcached. The response body is generated by (result is a string):

```
 response.getWriter().print(result);
```

My question is that, since the response body will be put into the memcached without modification, do I still need to create a customized HttpServletResponseWrapper? Can anyone provide any skeleton code for this filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be able to capture the servlet's output in your filter.

For this, you need to inject a customized `HttpServletResponseWrapper` that collects all output sent to `getWriter().print()` somewhere so that you can hand it off to memcached.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(3000); 
final PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "UTF-8"));

HttpServletResponse wrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return w;
    }

};
```

If this is a bigger project and you have more control over the network infrastructure, it might also be a good idea to not do this in Java, but just use a separate *proxy server* in front of the Servlet container. You can control what should be cached by the usual [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) HTTP headers (which you can set using a filter if the servlet does not already do it).

Comment: Thanks, does it mean that HttpServletResponseWrapper is a must even if the response body will not be modified?

Comment: How else are you going to get to the servlet's output? If you do nothing, it will write directly to the network connection to the browser, and your filter will not see any of it.

Comment: Thanks, now how do I get the response body out of the wrapper then?

Comment: It puts the response into the ByteArrayOutputStream baos, so you can call baos.getBytes().