# Servlets - How to inlude() a resource and get its response as a String?

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

I'm trying to implement a server-side API method that allows a batch of API requests to be executed as part of a single request, with the response for each request in the batch wrapped into a `JSONArray` that is returned to the client.

In essence, the client calls the server with a "batch" parameter along the lines of:

```
[{method: "getStatus" userId: "5"}, {method: "addFriend", userId: "5", friendId: "7"}]
```

This specifies a batch composed to two API calls.  What I want to do is execute each one, and combine the responses into something like:

```
[{status: "success", status: "At work..."}, {status: "error", message: "Friend not found!"}]
```

To execute the batch, I am iteratively calling `RequestDispatcher.include()`, as such:

```
String format = request.getParamter("format");  //carry the requested response format forward for each batched request
JSONArray batchResponse = new JSONArray();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/apiContext");
OverridableHttpRequest reusableRequest = new OverridableHttpRequest(request);
JSONArray requests = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(request.getParameter("batch"));
for (Object batchedRequest : requests) {
    reusableRequest.reset();  //clear all params and attribs

    //set the parameters to use for this request
    JSONObject requestParams = (JSONObject)batchedRequest;
    for (Object key : requestParams.keySet()) {
        reusableRequest.setParameter(key.toString(), requestParams.get(key).toString());
    }
    reusableRequest.setParameter("format", format);

    LOG.debug("including:  /apiContext?" + reusableRequest.getQueryString());

    //process the request as if it were received normally
    dispatcher.include(reusableRequest, response);  //FIXME:  how to get the response data for this include into 'batchResponse'?
}
```

Everything works well (all the batched requests are executed, and the server processes them correctly), but I can't figure out how to get the included response out so that I can add it to the results array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first try to avoid going through the servlet stack when handling the individual requests. Cannot you just call some of your business methods directly? I appreciate that you want to re-use the dispatching and parameter parsing logic, but maybe that part is not very complicated.

If that is not possible, maybe you can add a `request.setAttribute("theResult", jsonData)` into the individual handlers, so that you do not have to look at the text result, but can retrieve the data more easily.

If you still want to look at the response stream, you need to create a ResponseWrapper. For example check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784928/servlet-filter-for-caching).

Comment: I prefer going through the servlet stack in this case as there is a fair bit of access/permissions checking logic that it handles that I'd prefer to not re-implement or fold into the business methods themselves.  Basically each business method is annotated with a set of constraints that must be met for a call to that method to be allowed, and there is some generic code in the servlet stack related to validating those constraints.  Anyhow, the response wrapper looks like a good solution, but I tried it and the response keeps coming back as an empty string.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind that last bit about the writer.  I needed to manually call `flush()` on it before trying to access the data.  Problem solved.