# Caching rendered page for better performance

Tags: performance, spring, caching, ehcache

What  is the best way caching all page content in application based on spring framework ? I want use cache to remember all rendered pages for the same urls (I don't want use Squid server). It exists best practices to achieved acceptable result ? I want reduce cost of processing data and rendering page .
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a **reverse proxy** for caching is usually the right choice, since it can be deployed on a separate machine and allows more flexibility in general. Consider using [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/), if Squid doesn't fit your requirements. You may also check your "regular"  proxy server for existing caching modules (most servers support content caching in some way).

If you're looking for a pure **Java** solution, then a caching [filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) should do the trick. Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784928/servlet-filter-for-caching) for a template.

Also, consider setting *Expires* and *Cache-Control* headers for client-side/proxy caching in a separate filter. An example Tomcat configuration can be found [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Expires_Filter).